# Second popup box appears when opening a textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got some code that opens a textbox so the user can input an EAN and then it scrapes the web. It all works fine except for some reason a mysterious second textbox opens with the original one and unless you use that one to close the program, it stops responding.

```py
class MyDialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):     #Pop-up textbox

        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)

        Label(top, text="Product EAN").pack()       #pop-up box text

        self.e = Entry(top, cursor = "xterm", width=25)     #Input textbox
        self.e.pack(padx=40)

        b = Button(top, text="Submit", command=self.ok, cursor = "hand2")   #Submit button for pop-up box
        b.pack(pady=5)

....


root = Tk()
d = MyDialog(root)
root.wait_window(d.top)
```

That's all the code to do with textboxes - self.ok is the scraper so is unimportant to this issue. Could someone explain to me or help me fix the issue as I can't see why the following picture is the output from that.

[image: Double textbox?]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are opening a `Tk()` window and then another, `TopLevel()` window on top of that, if all you want is one window, the you just use the `Tk()` window. (The problem is a little unclear, but this is what I assume you are asking).

To fix this you can just remove the `TopLevel()` window. Like so:

```py
class MyDialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):     #Pop-up textbox

        Label(parent, text="Product EAN").pack()       #pop-up box text

        self.e = Entry(parent, cursor = "xterm", width=25)     #Input textbox
        self.e.pack(padx=40)

        b = Button(parent, text="Submit", command=self.ok, cursor = "hand2")   #Submit button for pop-up box
        b.pack(pady=5)

root = Tk()
d = MyDialog(root)
root.mainloop()
```